# South Doesn't Seem to Like PostgreSQLUUIDField

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-extensions

I'm having an issue using django_extensions.db.fields.PostgreSQLUUIDField with my Django models because South will keep trying to force the field to become a CharField every time schemamigration is run.

As a result I seem to be forced to hand-edit the migrations to remove:

```
db.alter_column('testapp_testmodel', 'guid', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=64, primary_key=True))
```

and edit the frozen model definitions below from:

```
'guid': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '64', 'primary_key': 'True'}),
```

to:

```
'guid': ('django_extensions.db.fields.PostgreSQLUUIDField', [], {'max_length': '64', 'primary_key': 'True'}),
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: maybe you should look this: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customfields.html#custom-fields

Comment: I did try that, however it didn't produce a different result. In fact, there's a small bit of information on that page which says: "Note that you must always specify a field as allowed, even if specifies no new rules of its own - the alternative is that South must presume all fields without any new rules specified only have the options of their parents, which is wrong some of the time."

That implies that if the options of the parents are the same, that I don't have to do anything.

Comment: I think the opposite: "Note that you must **always** specify a field as allowed, even if specifies no new rules of its own - the alternative is that South must presume all fields without any new rules specified only have the options of their parents, which is wrong some of the time.", could you put how do you added a rule for this "new" field?

Comment: I put this in my models.py where the field is used:
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^django_extensions\.db\.fields\.PostgreSQLUUIDField"])